# Meaning of "off"

Tags: word-meaning

I heard a commentator say:

> Aston Villa beat Arsenal and move two points **off** leaders Liverpool.

Does "off" mean "from" in this context?

Comment: As I've said many times now, You really must stop trying to assign "meaning" to each individual word in English constructions you don't understand. In this context, Aston didn't take 2 points ***away from*** Liverpool - their victory over Arsenal increased their (Villa's) points score so it was ***only 2 points less than Liverpool's.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I still don't understand. In your explanation does ***off*** mean exactly *away* or *from*?

Comment: FF just told you: two points less than Liverpool's points.

Comment: I need £1,000 to fix my car. I have saved £998. I am £2 off my target! Or, I asked a colleague to guess my age. He guessed 50. I am 48, so he was off by two, as he would also have been if he had guessed 46.

Comment: @Nyambek Am I right in assuming that you checked a dictionary before asking this question, found many different definitions of "off", and thought "from" might be the right one? If so, you should say that in the question.

Comment: Both "off" and "from" have many meanings, so even a "Yes" answer won't be helpful here, because you still won't know which meaning of "from" fits the context. Incidentally, the answer is "Yes", one of the meanings of "from" has the same meaning as "off" in that example sentence.

Comment: @gotube As you know, being a language teacher, dictionaries are no place to go for the meaning or usage of prepositions. Otherwise we wouldn't have lessons based around them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment doesn't help much because it ignores the useful generalisation or metaphor underpinning this usage, which would be useful for other learners. We use *off* when we talk about the distance from a ***target***. In no other sense does the usage of the preposition *off* make sense in this context.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: You can say *I **took** the applicant off the waiting list* as well as *I **moved** him off...*, without changing the meaning. But if we change OP's ***move*** to ***took*** the meaning (of ***off***?) obviously *does* change. This OP *repeatedly* asks for the context-specific meaning of individual elements within multi-word idiomatic usages, but I see no evidence that's ever been a helpful line of inquiry.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. As with every aspect of learning English, quality lessons are better than quality dictionaries, but dictionaries alone are quite helpful if a preposition has a meaning you haven't learned about, especially if there's a good example sentence to demonstrate that meaning. A learner doesn't have to go through lessons to learn each function of every preposition.

Answer (score 4):

Please try to understand the sentence not the word.

Off means "off".  You could *rephrase* as "Aston Villa move (in the league table) to a position two points away from the position held by Liverpool, who are the leaders in the league"  Or "two points below Liverpool."

But this is part of the normal meaning of "off": "away from a position upon".

I think the sentence is easy to understand when considered as a whole sentence.  It says one team beat another team, and then describes the effect this has on the league position. You will "miss the wood for the trees" if you try to understand word by word.

Comment: What does "away from a position upon" mean?

Comment: This misses the only useful generalisation here which is that we use *off* like this when we are talking about the divergence from some kind of target.

Comment: "away from a position upon" is a dictionary gloss.  Probably Cambridgd.

Comment: Ok, but my question was what does it mean?